# Liberty CWWKZ0002E and ZipError when deploying webapps from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, websphere-liberty

We are deploying 3 webapps in a liberty server (16.0.0.4) and frequently get ziperrors and messages like below (this is fairly easy to reproduce):

[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application XYZ. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: java.util.zip.ZipError: jzentry == 0,
jzfile = 693877616,
total = 1148,
name = C:\opt\IBM\wlp\usr\servers\XYZ\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\220\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.classloading.sharedlibrary_84.cache\lib\db2jcc.jar,
i = 329,
message = null

It seems to be erratic but easier to reproduce on slower machines so I suspect a race condition, but it may be as simple as the cache clearing during a server Clean is non-blocking?

Deploying the webapps as war files rather than linked via xml files back to projects does not experience this problem.

I've used the beans.xml with bean-discovery-mode="all" with no effect. We are using injection of different classes in two of the three web applications.

Note the directory number in the path to the cache differs from run to run.

This has been present since at least version 16.0.0.2 of Liberty. Is there a workaround for this problem or does anyone know if will be fixed in the December release?

Comment: The title may be a bit misleading -- the errors occur starting the server. My intent was to differentiate using references back to projects in Eclipse using xml files in the apps directory rather than deploying the web apps via war files in the apps directory.

Comment: I haven't seen this error pop up before.  Could you include some steps on how to reproduce this issue?  Also, is it halting your application processes or is it simply generating errors in logs?  If the former, may be best to open a PMR with IBM support.

Comment: Unfortunately, it occurs when starting the liberty server, but not consistently. It causes a web application from starting properly so you have to stop the server and restart it. It seems to move from one jar to another in the set of cache directories in the liberty server workarea under the org.eclipse.osgi directory.

Comment: Cleaning the server doesn't seem to clear out these cache directories and deleting them has caused problems (e.g., it would be nice if removing the entire workarea directory tree would cause it to be recreated when starting Eclipse with --clean...). There are situations where a jar file causes a problem in one of the cache directories that is no longer related to the server environment (e.g., there is no longer a reference to the jar in the shared library directory, nor in any projects).

This may be related to loading many (135) jar files in a shared library when also using code injection.

Comment: In one case, there was a zip file that included some other embedded zip files and one of these embedded zip files appeared to have a problem (so this is a valid error IMHO). However, the other problems (like the originally posted db2jcc.jar had no errors.

I have tried cleaning up the shared library directory and the frequency of problems has been reduced. But, I don't know if it was a race condition or if I removed some errant zip or jar file and the error reported wasn't naming the exact zip or jar that really caused the problem.

Comment: Note: trying to list multiple fileset entries in the shared library or assigning multiple shared libraries to an application in Liberty does not appear to work (only one gets loaded) so this is why I have such a large, single shared library entry. I'll try to discuss with Andy off line.

Comment: This problem has gone away as I've moved to newer Eclipse versions so I'll close it, but really don't know what was the root of the errors being reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has gone away with migrating projects to newer releases of Eclipse, so closing.